what is the rationale behind the number of testnet entrypoints?
I noticed there are three testnet entrypoints, wherein entrypoint2 and entrypoint3 appear to resolve to the same IP. Why is it structured this way, and in the case that it's a way to reserve the host name, why are entrypoint4 & entrypoint5 not also reserved for parity with devnet?

Could you link the specific testnet entry points you are referring to?
